# Label detection mouse click c++

Tags: c++, mouseevent

I'm trying to build a simple API in c++. It detects which button of my mouse I click on my window and it shows a MessageBox saying which button was clicked. I also managed to show in a messageBox when I release the button of my mouse. But I can't use both at the same time.

It is possible, instead using messageBox, inserting text of which button was clicked in a label, and change it depending of which button was pressed/released?

I use a switch with differents cases for each button pressed/released. Tell me if you have something for me, would be appreciated. Can show my code if you want !

Comment: quite unclear... "I can't use both at the same time" what do you mean? You cannot click and realease a mouse button at the same time. What messageBox/label are you talking about? Do you use some framework?

Comment: btw the `api` tag says "DO NOT USE", i removed it

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  If you have some code, then we may be able to provide more specific answers.

Comment: @user463035818 what I meant was that if I clicked, a messageBox was shown to say I clicked but when I released, the messageBox did not appear to say I released the button

Comment: @Eljay check my answer, think its good !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution.

First declareda label.

```
#define ID_LABEL 1
static HWND myLabel;
```

Then created it.

```
case WM_CREATE:
myLabel = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"),TEXT("hello"),
                       WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,50,50,150,25,
                       hwnd,(HMENU) ID_LABEL,NULL,NULL);
                       break;
```

And then for each button pressed/released, I edit the text. Example for when i press the left button of my mouse.

```
 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
               myLabel = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"),TEXT("left button pressed"),
                       WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,50,50,150,25,
                       hwnd,(HMENU) ID_LABEL,NULL,NULL);
                       break;
```

And it's working. Is anyway a better way to do it ?

Comment: What would you consider *better*?  I would recommend using a GUI framework as better.

Comment: Was just asking ! It's working but you know, sometimes we can improve and upgrade our products ! But thank you for the suggestion !